# Making a dir using uuid as a directory in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-management

```
import os
impoer uuid
wallet_filepath = os.path.join( 'PWD', str(uuid.uuid4().hex) , '.bin')
print (wallet_filepath)
print (os.path.exists(wallet_filepath))
print (os.stat(wallet_filepath))
```

This is the **OUTPUT** that I am getting from this code.

> /home/user/randomTests/b1c51a61c235479aa0964e14db7135d6/.bin
>
> False
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "testDir.py", line 9, in 
>       print (os.stat(wallet_filepath))
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/randomTests/b1c51a61c235479aa0964e14db7135d6/.bin'

Answer (score 2):

You never created the directory! You're just creating a string path and storing it in `wallet_filepath`.

You can use [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) to create the directory recursively (i.e, create all intermediate-level directories as well, needed to create the final dir):

```
wallet_filepath = os.path.join( 'PWD', str(uuid.uuid4().hex) , '.bin')
print (wallet_filepath)
if not os.path.exists(wallet_filepath) :
    os.makedirs(directory)
print (os.stat(wallet_filepath))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the answer given to use `os.makedirs()`, you may want to validate if your `.join` statement is actually what you want.

If you want "`/home/user/randomTests/b1c51a61c235479aa0964e14db7135d6/.bin`", keep using:

```
wallet_filepath = os.path.join( 'PWD', str(uuid.uuid4().hex) , '.bin')
```

If you want "`/home/user/randomTests/b1c51a61c235479aa0964e14db7135d6.bin`", use:

```
wallet_filepath = os.path.join( 'PWD', str(uuid.uuid4().hex) + '.bin')
```